# UISwipeGestureRecognizer causes jerkiness

Tags: swift, xcode, swipe, gesture, swift5

I use `UISwipeGestureRecogniser` in my `UITabBarController`:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.selectedIndex = Values.menuSelectedIndex
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        /*if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
            if (topController is HomeVC) {
                if (sender.direction == .left) {
                    self.selectedIndex += 1
                }
                else if (sender.direction == .right) {
                    self.selectedIndex -= 1
                }
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

<s>When the topController is anything other than HomeVC, the swipe gesture should do nothing.</s> Unfortunately, it causes jerkiness when scrolling left and right.

**Edit**

UIApplication.topViewController() is an extension to get the current `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `UIApplication.topViewController()`. is it a static function in `UIApplication` extension? can you show its implementation as well?

Comment: I would use `didSet` on `selectedIndex` and put a breakpoint there and make sure that it's not being called when the `topViewController` is not `HomeVC`

Comment: @TalCohen I placed a breakpoint inside `if (topController is HomeVC)` and it is not called. If I comment out all the code inside `handleSwipes` the jerkiness problem is still there.

Comment: Maybe there's a conflict between the gestures. You can implement the gesture delegate method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaniouslyWith:otherGesture` and return true. check out this article -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaniouslyWith:otherGesture` would not work for me because I am using `NMAMapViewDelegate` and `NMAMapGestureDelegate`.

I got this working simply by removing the gesture whenever on a `UIViewController` that should not be calling `handleSwipes`.

In `TabBarController` I added:

```
lazy var leftSwipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
lazy var rightSwipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))

public func addGestures() {
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}

public func removeGestures() {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}
```

and in any UIViewControllers that should not call `handleSwipes`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    (navigationController?.tabBarController as? TabBarController)?.removeGestures()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    (navigationController?.tabBarController as? TabBarController)?.addGestures()
}
```